# Moving domain name to new host but same domain needed in old host

Tags: domain, redirect

we have a website with domain name as www.abc.com the domain has one global site and 30 country sites urls will look as www.abc.com/global/index.aspx and www.abc.com/uk/index.aspx but now we are redesigning the global site and moving to new host environment, for every periodic time we going to move country sites one by one.

when we move the global site we will move the domain name to new host environment this will effect the country sites in old host. Is there any alternate way we can retain the domain name in old host ?

Comment: You should be using different hostnames for your country-specific sites. It would make this easy, and it is also much better for SEO ([see what Google says about this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en)).

Comment: Unless I've missed something obvious in that post, they don't explicitly say that you should use different hostnames (sub-domains, etc..) for different countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real way you can achieve this would be to plunk a reverse proxy down in front of your servers and make routing decisions based on the URL path requested.

There's any number of products or solutions out there that can do it, chief among the free ones are [HAproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/), [mod_proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_proxy) and [NGinx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/). On the commercial side, F5's BigIP [LTM](https://f5.com/products/modules/local-traffic-manager) products, Citrix [Netscalers](https://www.citrix.com/products/netscaler-application-delivery-controller/overview.html) and any other Application Delivery Controler (aka Load balancer) can do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion we don't have direct access to the servers i will check with my hosting team they already suggested for adding a sub domain (like international.adc.com ) for country sites  when we move global site to new host.

Comment: some more info:
1. domain name was created very long at that time i was not in this company and my customer want same domain for all the sites in new host.
2. i really don't want to create a temporary sub domain in old host it really makes mess like setting redirection for each application, SEO ranking all these are delicate and sensitive.
3. website was hosted on three servers under load balance.

I don't have much knowledge on server side I'm a frontend and backend developer i will check with my hosting team what you suggested. People do share if you know any other way thanks

Comment: I found some useful link http://www.askapache.com/hosting/reverse-proxy-apache.html thanks @GregL